# plot cylindrical coordinate using an x y file in gnuplot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, cylindrical

I would like to make a 3D plot with gnuplot using the interface.txt file ([File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ahFuIGPwOZt0zZHc0vPOMxOwt3K_MpQf/view?usp=sharing)).
Knowing that I have a y-axis rotation invariance.
This figure represents a 2D section (plot 'interface.txt' u 2:1) [image: 2D section]

Here's what I'd like to have with gnuplot but I don't know how to plot it.
I would like to get this picture but for theta = [0:2*pi].
[image]
I tried this code but for now i don't know how to plot it

```
reset
set angles degrees
set mapping cylindrical

splot for [t=1:360:2] 'interface.txt' u t:1:(sqrt($2**2+$1**2))
```

If you have any idea ?
Thanks you !

Comment: your data is an open curve. Should it be closed somehow? If yes, how?

Comment: yes I think we can close the curve using pm3d. And maybe with Special-filenames and my data file we can plot this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the example below satisfies your expectations.
Since your original curve is not closed, this is not a body but a surface.
For `pm3d` to do the "connections" between the rotated curves, I guess you have to have add a single empty line between the rotated curves. You can get this with the "trick" of plotting a dummy array with one element: `plot A u ("") w table`. I hope that there are better solutions.

**Code:**

```
### rotation of a curve
reset session

set angle degrees
set table $Rotation
    array A[1]   # dummy array for plotting a single empty line
    do for [i=0:360:15] {
        plot "interface.txt" u ($2*cos(i)):($2*sin(i)):1 w table
        plot A u ("") w table
    }
unset table

set pm3d hidden3d depthorder

# set view equal xyz   # uncomment to have equal x,y,z scales
set view 30,50,1.3     # scale 1.3 to reduce white space around

splot $Rotation u 1:2:3 w pm3d lt -2 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! almost perfect, now we just have to close the two surfaces to get one body

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to add "set contour base with isosample and pm3d map" on the xy plane ? while keeping my solid 3D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you, it is almost perfect.
Now it try to close my 2 surfaces.
[image]

So we need to link the edge of the curve to get one body.
For that I use stats :

[image]

And then the final code :

```
### rotation of a curve
reset session

set print $interface
stats 'interface.txt' nooutput
print sprintf("%g %g", STATS_max_y, STATS_pos_max_y)
print sprintf("%g %g", STATS_max_y, -STATS_pos_max_y)
set angle degrees
set table $Rotation
    array A[1]   # dummy array for plotting a single empty line
    do for [i=0:360:10] {
        plot "interface.txt" u ($2*cos(i)):($2*sin(i)):1 w table
    plot "interface.txt" u ($2*cos(i)):($2*sin(i)):(-$1) w table
    plot $interface u ($1*cos(i)):($1*sin(i)):2 w table
        plot A u ("") w table
    }
unset table

unset key
set border
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set view 62, 8, 1.245, 1.0

set ticslevel 0
set pm3d depthorder interpolate 4,4 lighting specular 0.6 at s

# set view equal xyz   # uncomment to have equal x,y,z scales

splot $Rotation u 1:2:3 w pm3d lt -2 notitle
### end of code
```

[image]

Comment: glad that it worked. Then this should be the accepted answer, my answer was just helpful ;-). Keep in mind when creating a datablock with `set print $interface`, when your done creating the datablock use `set print` or `unset print` to stop printing everything to this datablock.In case you want to print something to the gnuplot console window.